# regex preg_replace in foreach loop

Tags: php, regex

I have the below simple replace working

```
<?php
$mydata= '15-2003';
$pattern = '/[-]/';
$replacement = ' ';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $mydata);
?>
```

Which outputs 15 2003

However when I put it in my foreach loop it doesn't seem to work?

I have this

```
<?php foreach ($tests as $test): ?>
<tr>
<?php
$mydata= htmlout($test['f']);
$pattern = '/[-]/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $mydata);
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which outputs 15-2003
Where am I going wrong here?

htmlout is the below custom function.

```
<?php
function html($text)
{
return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
function htmlout($text)
{
echo html($text);
}
```

When I do var_dump($mydata);
I get NULL

Comment: please show what $tests contains

Comment: For such a simple replacement, [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will do the job just fine. I also note that in your looping example you are replacing with an empty string instead of a space like your first example.

Comment: You know that you could use `str_replace` here, right?

Comment: what is [`htmlout`](http://pa2.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=htmlout&lang=en&scope=quickref) and what does it return? (if this is converting to unicode you may not be replacing the same hyphen you think you are...)

Comment: First, for such a simple replace you should use `str_replace`, which is faster. Can you do a simple `var_dump($mydata);` ?

Comment: @poncha I don't mess about, me... :-D

Comment: I have edited the question to include what I get for var_dump($mydata); and what htmlout is. I get a similar result with str_relace() it looks like @brad-christie might be right about the unicode, how would I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work as intended because `htmlout()` `echo`es the value instead of `return`ing it.

Consider replacing

```
$mydata= htmlout($test['f']);
```

with

```
$mydata= html($test['f']);
```

What happends in your code is that it simply prints out the original string, returns `NULL` to `$mydata` and then you echo a `NULL` which doesn't show anything.

Comment: Thanks I understand now.  Now I have this working I will change from preg_replace to str_replace()